# angular material flex-layout

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
<mat-card fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex.sm="60" fxFlexOffset.sm="20" fxFlex.md="60" fxFlexOffset.md="20" fxFlex.lg="40" fxFlexOffset.lg="30"
  fxFlex.xl="40" fxFlexOffset.xl="30">
  <mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="messageForm" class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;" fxFlex="20" fxFlex.sm="100">
        <input matInput formControlName="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter your title">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;" fxFlex="80" fxFlex.sm="100">
        <input matInput formControlName="content" name="content" placeholder="Enter your message">
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-icon>send</mat-icon> Send
    </button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Why is it that when the size of the screen is "sm". the mat-form-field should be fxflex="100" but the other mat-form-field won't go down. It will show like 50/50. I want to achieve, if the screen is small. the size of both mat-form-field is 100 so they will consume the entire row. It will have 2 rows now instead of in 1 row. they have same size.

Comment: You can use units of measure in the fxFlex attribute (e.g. px, %). Here is a link to the basic usage: [https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview)